# The inhomogeneous Maxwell equation ${*}\mathrm d{*}F=J^\flat$ is only true for the signature $(+---)$?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, conventions, mathematics

In short, we would expect that considering the Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and the Riemannian manifold $(M,-g)$ leads to the same Maxwell equations, i.e. we would expect that
$\newcommand{\imult}{\mathbin{\lrcorner}}$
$\newcommand{\hodge}{{*}}$
$\newcommand{\dif}{\mathrm{d}}$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}\dif F=0\\\hodge\dif\hodge F=J^\flat\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is true for both metrics. However I think that this is not the case and I would like to know whether my reasoning is correct:

On the one hand, equations like
$$F=\dif(A^\flat)$$
and
$$f^\flat=qU\imult F$$
show that $F$ does depend on the signature: If $F$ is the EM tensor w.r.t. to one signature, then $-F$ is the EM tensor w.r.t. the other signature. However, then
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
    \hodge\dif\hodge F=J^\flat
\end{equation}
is not invariant under a change of the signature: $(1)$ is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
    \dif\hodge F=*J^\flat
\end{equation}
and we see that the RHS is independent of the signature, but the LHS does depend on the signature because $F$ does (the $*$ on $\Omega^2$ and $\dif$ do not depend on the signature).

In summary, the equality can only hold for one signature - as I said, I think that $(+---)$ is the "correct" one. Am I right?

---

$^1$ I think that $\dif\hodge F=-{*}J^\flat$ for the other signature.

Comment: Yes, there is a minus in the RHS depending on the metric signature (-2 or +2).

Comment: @DanielC Thank you for the comment! May I ask what the numbers -2 and +2 mean?

Comment: @Filippo I assume it means the sum of the eigenvalues of the metric.

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure I understand. I thought that "eigenvalues" are only defined for vector space endomorphisms.

Comment: Or did you simply mean that 1-1-1-1=-2 and -1+1+1+1=+2?

Comment: Yes, you are right, technically "eigenvalue" is not the right word (I was trying to avoid using the word "trace"). But you can still always diagonalize the metric (with both indicies lowered) and sum the values. And, yes, I think DanielC meant $1-1-1-1=-2$ and $-1+1+1+1=+2$. I've personally never seen the signature computed like that, I've only ever seen it computed as the sign of the determinant of the metric, but it works in this context.

Comment: @Andrew Knowing the trace is actually equivalent to knowing the signature, whereas different signatures lead to the same determinant, right?

Comment: @Filippo Ah I see, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @DanielC Do you know a reference or have you simply verified this on your own?

Comment: @Filippo You can check it by yourself, but use Lorentz-tensor components, not fancy diff-geom notation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you construct the theory as being based on *vector fields* $A$ and then defining $F = \mathrm{d}(A^\flat)$, then there is a dependence on the metric signature here.

However, an alternative formalization is to construct the theory with the connection form $A$ being the fundamental quantity, and likewise a current form $J$. If we want to write everything in terms of forms anyway, there is little point to starting with vector fields. It is then the vector fields $A^\sharp, J^\sharp$ that are signature dependent, not $F$ or the equations of motion.

You just need to pick a convention and stick with it, neither of these approaches is more "correct" than the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate the confirmation. I am afraid I don't understand the point of the second paragraph though. How do the signature-independent equations of motions look like? The equations of motion in my question clearly show that $F$ does depend on the signature.